# Copy across two additional columns where there is a match

Tags: vba, excel

I have two spreadsheets

main.xlsm

[image]

uat.xlsx

[image]

If there is a match between column A (1) in main.xlsm and column B (2) in uat.xlsx, I want to also copy across the values in column C (3) in uat.xlsx to column N (14) in main.xlsm, and the values in column D (4) in uat.xlsx to column Q (14) in main.xlsm **on the matching row in main.xlsm**.

I've made a head start on the code, but would like to add the above to it - how would I go about doing this?

```
Sub UAT_Update()
Dim wshT As Worksheet
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wshS As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    Dim m As Long
    Dim cel As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wshT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Check whether uat.xlsx is already open
    Set wbk = Workbooks("uat.xlsx")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If wbk Is Nothing Then
        ' If not, open it
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Working\uat.xlsx")
    End If

    ' Set worksheet on uat.xlsx
    Set wshS = wbk.Worksheets("owssvr")
    m = wshT.Cells(wshT.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Optional - clear columns on main.xlsm
    ' wshT.Range(wshT.Cells(1, 13), wshT.Cells(m, 13)).ClearContents

    ' Loop though cells in column A on main.xlsm
    For r = 1 To m
        ' Can we find the value in column B of uat.xlsm?
        Set cel = wshS.Columns(2).Find(What:=wshT.Cells(r, 1).Value, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not cel Is Nothing Then
            ' If so, enter "Yes" in column M - Comms Sent?
                wshT.Cells(r, 13).Value = "Yes"
            ' Enter "Yes" in column O - VDA Deployed?
                wshT.Cells(r, 15).Value = "Yes"
            ' Enter "5.6.200" in column P - Version
                wshT.Cells(r, 16).Value = "5.6.200"
        End If
    Next r

    ' Update column headers
    wshT.Cells(1, 13).Value = "Comms Sent?"
    wshT.Cells(1, 14).Value = "OTP"
    wshT.Cells(1, 15).Value = "VDA Deployed?"
    wshT.Cells(1, 16).Value = "VDA Version"
    wshT.Cells(1, 17).Value = "Migration Date"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Facing any issues with above code ?

Comment: Why are you doing this with VBA? You can use lookup formulas instead which are much faster and don't involve kicking off a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the above code working well.

I think you should change the line --> `wshT.Cells(r, 15).Value = "Yes"` To  `wshT.Cells(r, 15).Value = cel.offset(0,1).value`

Updated:

```
If Not cel Is Nothing Then                
                wshT.Cells(r, 15).Value = cel.offset(0,1).value

End If
```